# SSH local port forwarding on a remote not listening port: the connection succeeds?

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I discovered today that if I ssh-forward the local port X to ssh server port Y, and no process is listening on port Y, I can still connect to local port X (I don't get the usual "connection refused" error).

I did my test with 2 different SSH clients on a windows host connecting to a linux server.

After a bit of reflexion, I came to the conclusion that from a pure network point of view, this is the behaviour I should expect: the SSH client is actually listening on localhost:X, so the connection is possible.

Nevertheless, this leads to a problematic situation in which I have an apparently connected socket that talks to nobody. Even sending data on the socket is a successful operation.

So my question: does the SSH protocol manage this situation in some ways, i.e. do I have strategies for detecting this situation? And if yes, may I hope support for this feature on some SSH clients and APIs (today I'm using ssh.net, that does not seem to offer this feature).

If not, how would you proceed for detecting the situation? Timeout on answer?

Thanks for your help,
Alberto.

Answer (score 0):

The only logical behavior would be to close client connection if the server can't connect to the remote side, but that would not be much better than just a hanging connection.

Also there can happen situation when the SSH server is waiting for the remote connection for a minute or two before giving up, so the client's connection will be opened for this period of time anyway.

So there's actually no logical alternative rather than a hanging client connection.